# Why can't order id be placed as a foreign key in the customer table?

Tags: entity-relationship

"The unique identifier of the entity on the “one side” of the one-to-many relationship is placed as a foreign key in the table representing the entity on the “many side.”

Why can't the primary key of the entity on the "many side" of the one-to-many relationship be placed as a foreign key in the table representing the entity on the "one side" ?

Ex. one-to-many relationship between Customer and Order
A customer can place many orders, but each order can be placed by only one customer.

Why can't order id be placed as a foreign key in the customer table?

Answer (score 0):

Any one entity can have only one value of the foreign key, and therefore can reference only one related entity.  The referenced entity is thus on the (a) "one" side of the relationship by definition.  The entity bearing the FK can be either the other "one" side of a one:one relationship or the "many" side of a one:many relationship; the difference is whether foreign key values may be duplicated in more than one entity of that type.